# Categorising by date in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I format Excel to read the date in a cell (A), compare that against dates in other cells (B,C,D etc), and if A is a date before B, highlight row in a particular colour; if A is a date before C, highlight row in a particular colour etc.

Example:

A is 15/11/2014

B is 07/11/2014 (Green)
C is 14/11/2014 (Red)
D is 21/11/2014 (Blue)

Based on this, the row should be Blue as it is before D.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to look at Conditional formatting.  Under the Home Tab, in the Styles Group, click Conditional Formatting.  You can set up the rule (format by value probably).  One way to do it is to add multiple rules (one for before red date, one for before blue date, etc.) and then check the box for stop if true for each one.

In the example you provided, first rule would be: if A < B then format green.  Second rule: if A < C then format Red.  Third rule: if a < D then format Blue.  There's also an option to do multiple ranges in one rule (depending on your version of Excel).  That would probably be simpler.  You should be able to use relative (A1 instead of $A$1) references for your equations, so that when you use the format painter to paint the entire column the comparison formula travels with it.  For more detailed information on Conditional Formatting:

https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Does that help?